# QTableView - row selection, focus on fields

Tags: qt, qtableview

I'd like to select the whole rows in QTableView and only rows. User shouldn't know that there are any cells. I can set a proper SelectionMode but still:

- each cell has a rounded corner when it's row is selected
- moving mouse on QTableView moves "focus" and selects cell under a cursor

How can I avoid this problems?

Answer (score 1):

Please try QTableView's method

```
setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
```

Comment: setting behaviour to SelectRows and Mode to SingleSelection ends in situation, when I can select rows, but still moving mouse over QTableView changes color of cells under it. And still each cell in selected row has rounded corners.

Comment: Setting both behaviour and mode like this temporarily allowed me to call selectRow (while the user has Shift down) without selecting multiple rows, great.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a delegate.

Here's how: http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/how_can_i_remove_the_dotted_rectangle_from_the_cell_that_has_focus_in_my_qt

In Python: http://imath.diandian.com/post/2013-07-09/40051407386

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

I ended up using a `QTreeView`, which supports multiple columns (like a table). The default drag'n'drop behavior lets you drag, move and reorder only rows.

To make it look and behave like a row-interaction-only table, you need to set these properties:

- allColumnsShowFocus = true (so you don't see the focus frame around a specific (column) item)
- headerHidden = false (to enable table headers)
- itemsExpandable = false (can be ignored, if all other properties are set correctly)
- rootIsDecorated = false (this hides the expand handles for topLevelItems)
- selectionBehavior = SelectRows
- selectionMode = *SingleSelection* (or as you wish...)
- for moving rows:

  - dragEnabled = true
  - acceptDrops = true
  - showDropIndicator = true
  - editTriggers::selectedClicked = false
  - all item's item flags:

    - ItemIsSelectable = true
    - ItemIsDragEnabled = true
    - ItemIsDropEnabled = **false** (so you can't drag a topLevelItem to become child of another item)
    - ItemIsEnabled = true

Now if you only use topLevelItems, the treeView behaves as you want it.